# What is going wrong with the scope of 'flag' in my javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, web, xmlhttprequest, client-side-scripting

I am new to javascript and wrote the following script to send an HTTP request to my webserver and receive back the response. I defined a variable 'flag' that I will use later in the script. However, its value is not getting changed in the script even after receiving the response.

```
var flag=0;
loadDoc();
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.open("GET", "tt.html", true);
  xhttp.send();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange=test;
  function test() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.body.innerHTML = this.responseText;
      flag=1;
      console.log(flag);     // outputs 1
    }
  }
  console.log(flag);     // outputs 0 (It should have returned '1')
}
```

Comment: Ajax requests are asynchronous.  The `flag = 1` will not have happened by the time the outer conole log happens.

Comment: That's due to the async behavior. Last console log executes before even you get your response.

Comment: Wait for few seconds and then manually console log your flag. It should be 1. By that time, response must be received.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, how can I use async/await here to resolve the issue? Thnx in advance for the help..

Comment: That is covered in the duplicate post.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with the scope, it's to do with the timing. Yes, you might want to use `async`/`await`.